# angular routing start with second level

Tags: .net, angular, routes

I am working on angular 4 project where I am converting the previous MVC project front end to angular.

The issue i am facing is our base url is not static and can be anything(string) which we handel in MVC route mapper. I tried in angular but it does not work.

I tried below routing table.

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: '**', component: RewardComponent },
        { path: '**/**', component: RewardComponent }
        ]
```

Now when I try running .

http://localhost:50525/home  - this works fine

http://localhost:50525/{anything}  - works fine

but as soon as I go a level more I get error.

http://localhost:50525/{anything}/{anything}

I get following error...

```html
   

 zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js 404 (Not Found)
    scheduleTask @ zone.js:2933
    ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
    Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
    Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
    (anonymous) @ zone.js:2966
    proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
    fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:1778
    ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:890
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:1777
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:2806
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:3384
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:3707
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:4099
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:4562
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:4831
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:407
    ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:392
    Zone.run @ zone.js:142
    (anonymous) @ zone.js:873
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
    Promise resolved (async)
    scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:585
    ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:414
    Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
    Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:256
    scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:871
    ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:981
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:4789
    import @ system.src.js:839
    (anonymous) @ system.src.js:1801
    (anonymous) @ (index):10
    (index):10 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js
     Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js
         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:39)
         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:31)
         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:47)
         at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:34)
         at invokeTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:14)
         at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17)
     Error loading http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js
         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:39)
         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:31)
         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:47)
         at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:34)
         at invokeTask (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:14)
         at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:50525/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17)
     Error loading http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js
```

Its like its trying to find maion.js in {anything folder.}

I am not even sure if the two level routing is possible in angular as I am new to these.

The location of main,js in system.js is set as following

```
 app: {
                main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
```

Thank you in advance for your help and I hope what I've written in the post it's helpful to understand my issue!

Comment: Difficult to know without seeing your systemjs setup or snippets but you possibly just need to switch the last 2 parts of your routes array around as the ** will match anything so will never check * * / * *

Comment: Thanks,but even if i remove that route and put exact match like                     { path: 'home/edit', component: HomeComponent }, i STILL error zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:50525/homeasadd/app/main.js 404 (Not Found)  ... its like when i go one level up in routing it looks for main.js in the folder ....

Comment: packages: {
            app: {
                main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
            ,
            'ng2-bs3-modal':
            { main: '/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }